# Remove entire key when matched with matched array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, for-loop

I am new to react, I have an object and an array, I want to get details of unmatched items from the object when compared with array values. I tried but shows all the data when consol.log. here is my code

```
var content:[
    0:{id:20, name:'Jack Daniel'}
    1:{id:21, name:'Sophie McDonald'}
    2:{id:22, name:'Jason Thomas'}
    3:{id:23, name:'Chris Williams'}
]

var filter:[Sophie McDonald, Chris Williams]

filterValues = content.filter(item=> {
            
    for(var i = 0;i<filter.length;i++) {
        if (item.name === filtered[i])
        {
            return item              
        }       
     } 
});
console.log(filteredValues)
  // returns  0:{id:21, name:'Sophie McDonald'}
  //          1:{id:23, name:'Chris Williams'}
```

But I need unmatched results,

```
filterValues = content.filter(item=> {
            
    for(var i = 0;i<filter.length;i++) {
        if (item.name !== filtered[i])
        {
            return item              
        }       
     } 
});
console.log(filteredValues)
// returns  0:{id:20, name:'Jack Daniel'}
//          1:{id:21, name:'Sophie McDonald'}
//          2:{id:22, name:'Jason Thomas'}
//          3:{id:23, name:'Chris Williams'}
```

Result must be

```
 0:{id:20, name:'Jack Daniel'}
 1:{id:22, name:'Jason Thomas'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `filter`, checking if the values of the array are present in your object values:

```js
const content = [{
    id: 20,
    name: 'Jack Daniel'
  },
  {
    id: 21,
    name: 'Sophie McDonald'
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    name: 'Jason Thomas'
  },
  {
    id: 23,
    name: 'Chris Williams'
  }
];

const values = ['Sophie McDonald', 'Chris Williams'];

const filteredValues = content.filter(({
  name
}) => !values.includes(name));

console.log(filteredValues);
```

Comment: Perfect! that worked. thanks for taking time

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work with a few edits to the format:

```js
let content = [
    {id:20, name:'Jack Daniel'},
    {id:21, name:'Sophie McDonald'},
    {id:22, name:'Jason Thomas'},
    {id:23, name:'Chris Williams'}
]

let filter = ["Sophie McDonald", "Chris Williams"]

let filterValues = content.filter(item=> {
    for(var i = 0;i<filter.length;i++) {
        if (item.name !== filter[i]){
            return item              
        }       
     } 
});

console.log(filterValues)
```

Comment: Not sure why it is not working on my end, but this was giving results
 const filteredValues = content.filter(({ name}) => !values.includes(name));